# A nice way to build a related content algorithm

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I am making a custom D7 module which has a block that lists related nodes of the current node you're viewing. The relation is determined by Taxonomy terms (from 1 vocab). The complication is that the related nodes need to be ordered by how many tags are matched in descending order.

How can you order nodes by matching tags? I have an idea of how to select nodes with matching tags, but have no clue as to how to order these by the number of matching tags. Any suggestions? Do it in SQL or in PHP?

Are there any modules that implement such functionality?

#### Simple case study for clarity

I have 2 content types: **basic_page**, **article**

Both of these content types have a same term reference field: **field_tags**

When someone opens a `basic_page` node that has been tagged with Tag A, Tag B and Tag C, I want to show `article` nodes that have been tagged with Tag A, Tag B and Tag C. But these `article` nodes need to be ordered by 'relevancy'. For example: the `article` nodes with all 3 tags matched must be at the top, and `article` nodes with 2 matching tags comes next, then the ones with 1 matching tag.

Comment: Maybe an average of levenshtein sums could fit? See [Levenshtein Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance), and [Levenshtein PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a list of similar nodes in Drupal 7/Views 3](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27844/how-to-create-a-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3)

Comment: @Letharion It's not a duplicate.

Comment: It's quite close :) The answer on that question, particularly the module there has helped me come up with a solution. Thanks @Letharion

Comment: @kiamlaluno I defer to your judgement, but I don't see why? If it's because the other question has "Views" in the title, then wouldn't it make more sense to just remove that?

Comment: @Letharion The other question is asking how to achieve something with Views, while this question is asking how to achieve something using a custom module. A question is about how to use a module to achieve something; the other question is about code to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was what I ended up writing to select nodes:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->addField('n', 'nid');
$query->addExpression('COUNT(n.nid)', 'ncount');
$query->innerJoin('taxonomy_index', 'ti', 'n.nid = ti.nid');
$query->condition('ti.tid', $tids, 'IN');
$query->condition('n.type', $types, 'IN');
$query->condition('n.nid', $node->nid, '<>'); // Exclude current node
$query->condition('n.status', 1); // Published
$query->condition(
  db_or()->condition('n.language', 'und')
         ->condition('n.language', $node->language)
);
$query->groupBy('n.nid');
$query->groupBy('n.title');
$query->groupBy('n.created');
$query->orderBy('ncount', 'DESC');
$query->range(0, 10);

$results = $query->execute();
```

Kudos to [Similar by Terms](http://drupal.org/project/similarterms) module, as I copied most of it from there. The magic happens when you order by `ncount` field.