# How to create a suggested articles block that uses taxonomy?

Tags: views, 7, blocks

I've been trying to create a view that uses taxonomy to generate suggested articles to users.

I wanted these articles generated according to their relation with the taxonomy term of the current article the user is reading.

How can I make this work?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/similarterms or see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32682/a-nice-way-to-build-a-related-content-algorithm

Comment: Since this one uses views, this is probably a more suitable dupe: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27844/how-to-create-a-list-of-similar-nodes-in-drupal-7-views-3

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Similar by Terms](https://www.drupal.org/project/similarterms) module. Here are some more details about it (from its project page):

> This Drupal module attempts to provide context for content items by displaying a view block with links to other similar content. Similarity is based on the taxonomy terms assigned to content. Views are available based on similarity within each of the defined vocabularies for a site as well as similarity within all vocabularies.
>
> What does this really mean? How should you use this module?
>
> 1. Create a freetagging vocabulary called "Tags" assigned to the content types on which you'd like to display the "Similar" view block.
> 2. Enable the view block called "Similar entries from the Tags vocabulary".
> 3. Add keyword tags to the content.
>
> You can also create own views and add similar by term Nid argument, sort handler and similarity as field. Now when you go to the page for a tagged content item, a block will show up displaying other content in descending order of common tags (terms).

**Note**: a stable version of this module is available for both D7 and D8!